# Local Jekyll Serve/Live Site discrepancy - "view on Gihtub" button missing

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

It's really a small things, but something I can't get out of my mind.

When running gh-pages locally with jekyll serve I get the "View on Github" button, but it's missing on the live page. Everything is up to date, and all files are the same both locally and live.

_config.yml

```
    keyword: "NFT, Crypto, Art, Token, Promotions, New Artists"
    url: "https://creepybits.github.io"          # your host, for absolute URL

    github_repo: "https://github.com/creepybits/creepybits.github.io.git" # you code repository
```

default.html

```
<header class="page-header" role="banner">
  <h1 class="project-name">{{ page.title | default: site.title | default: site.github.repository_name }}</h1>
  <h2 class="project-tagline">{{ page.description | default: site.description | default: site.github.project_tagline }}</h2>
  {% if site.github.is_project_page %}
    <a href="{{ site.github.repository_url }}" class="btn">View on GitHub</a>
  {% endif %}
  {% if site.show_downloads %}
    <a href="{{ site.github.zip_url }}" class="btn">Download .zip</a>
    <a href="{{ site.github.tar_url }}" class="btn">Download .tar.gz</a>
  {% endif %}
</header>
```

I just can't see where the problem is.

Edit:

Gemfile

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "github-pages", "~> 217", group: :jekyll_plugins
gem 'webrick', '~> 1.3', '>= 1.3.1'

group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 0.12"
  gem "jekyll-seo-tag", "~> 2.7.1"
  gem "jekyll-textile-converter"
  gem 'jekyll-opal', '~> 0.3.0'
  gem "jekyll-github-metadata"
  gem "jekyll-sitemap", "~> 1.4.0"
  gem 'jekyll-theme-cayman', '~> 0.2.0'
  gem 'jekyll-coffeescript', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.1'
end

platforms :mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin, :jruby do
  gem 'tzinfo', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.4'
  gem 'tzinfo-data', '~> 1.2021', '>= 1.2021.1'
end

gem "wdm", "~> 0.1.1", :platforms => [:mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin]
```

Command for launching website locally.

```
$ bundle exec jekyll serve
```

Comment: GitHub Pages is likely injecting the `site.github.*` variables. Could you please edit the question with your Gemfile, and the command you use to build/serve your site locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue in the header.

```
<header class="page-header" role="banner">
  <h1 class="project-name">{{ page.title | default: site.title | default: site.github.repository_name }}</h1>
  <h2 class="project-tagline">{{ page.description | default: site.description | default: site.github.project_tagline }}</h2>
 {% if site.github.is_project_page %}
    <a href="{{ site.github.repository_url }}" class="btn">View on GitHub</a>
  {% endif %}
  {% if site.show_downloads %}
    <a href="{{ site.github.zip_url }}" class="btn">Download .zip</a>
    <a href="{{ site.github.tar_url }}" class="btn">Download .tar.gz</a>
  {% endif %}
</header>
```

Changed

```
{% if site.github.is_project_page %}
```

to

```
{% if site.github.is_user_page %}
```

And now it works like a charm.